# Having trouble finding a maximum for each month

Tags: sql

I'm sure this is quite simple, but I am stuck on it. I have a table like this:

```
Month      Period  Value
May 2013   3       e
May 2013   2       k
May 2013   1       l
April 2013 5       z
April 2013 4       w
April 2013 3       t
April 2013 2       f
April 2013 1       j
```

I want to find the the value for the highest period of each month. For this data, that would be e for May 2013 and z for April 2013.

Comment: What if you added another record - Month: May 2013, Period: 3, Value: f.  Now you have multiple Values for the same Month, max(Period).  What would you want the result to be?

Comment: have you got an ID also? can month-period be duplicated?

Comment: Which is your RDBMS and version?

Comment: SQL Server 2012. Sorry to have left that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify what RDBMS you are using, but you can use a subquery to get the `max(period)` for each month and then join to your table to get the value:

```
select t1.month,
  t1.period,
  t1.value
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(period) period, month
  from yourtable
  group by month
) t2
  on t1.month = t2.month
  and t1.period = t2.period;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55dea/1).

If your database has windowing functions, then you can use `row_number()` to get the result:

```
select month, period, value
from 
(
  select month, period, value,
    row_number() over(partition by month order by period desc) rn
  from yourtable
) d
where rn = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55dea/3)

Comment: I love the SQL Fiddle demo. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A **generic SQL** solution that should work in most RDBMS:

```
SELECT month, period, value
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM tbl t1
   WHERE  t1.month = t.month
   AND    t1.period > t.period
   );
```

This one is **specific to Postgres** and a bit faster there:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (month)
       month, period, value
FROM   tbl t
ORDER  BY month, period DESC, value DESC;
```

I added `value DESC` to `ORDER BY` to break ties for equally great periods. You get the row with the greater value in this case.

[-> SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8f7a2/1)